# Error CORS con servidor spring boot tras enviar formulario desde angular

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cors

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer una aplicación full-stack y para ello estoy combinando angular para el frontend y spring boot para el backend. De momento tengo una página con un formulario de registro, pero cuando ejecuta la parte de registrar me sale el siguiente error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8080/login;jsessionid=6D49B9CB50F7D5763DD7885FEA209FBC'
> (redirected from 'http://localhost:8080/api/register') from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
> preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

He estado leyendo otras respuestas y varios foros al respecto pero sigo sin poder arreglarlo. Lo que he probado hasta ahora ha sido ejecutar angular con un proxy inverso:
angular.json
"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
"options": {
"proxyConfig": "proxy.conf.json"
}
Y dentro del proxy.conf.json:
"/api": {
"target": "http://localhost:8080",
"secure": false
}
}

También he intentado crear la configuración de CORS en spring boot de la siguiente forma:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/api/**")
            .allowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200") 
            .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "OPTIONS")
            .allowCredentials(true);
    }
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200"); 
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

Pero sigue sin funcionar, adjunto mi clase del controlador del formulario en spring boot con su respectivo servicio en ese orden:
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class RegisterController {

```
    @Autowired
    RegisterService registerService;

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody User user) {
        // Guarda el nuevo usuario en la base de datos
        if(registerService.registerUser(user)){
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Registro exitoso");
        }else{
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("El correo electrónico ya está registrado.");
        }

        
    }

@Service
public class RegisterService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public boolean registerUser(User user) {
        if(userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null){
            return false;
        }
        // Cifra la contraseña usando PBKDF2 antes de almacenarla en la base de datos
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(hashedPassword);
        user.setRole(roleRepository.findByName("JUGADOR"));
        // Luego, guarda el usuario en la base de datos
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }
```

Por último adjunto el envío del formulario desde angular donde también he metido las cabeceras que había encontrado en otras respuestas:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RegisterService {
  private apiUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/register'; 

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  registerUser(user: User): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Methods':'POST, GET',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:4200', 
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
    });

    // Configura las opciones de solicitud
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: headers,
    };
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, user, httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Y por ultimo la lógica del formulario:

```
constructor(private registerService: RegisterService, private router: Router) {}

  async register() {
    if (this.user.password !== this.confirmPassword) {
      // Las contraseñas no coinciden, muestra un mensaje de error
      this.passwordsDoNotMatch = true;
      return;
    }
    // Restablecer el mensaje de error si las contraseñas coinciden
    this.passwordsDoNotMatch = false;

    
    try {
      await firstValueFrom(this.registerService.registerUser(this.user));
      // Manejar el éxito del registro aquí
      console.log('Registro exitoso');
      // Redirigir al usuario a la página de inicio de sesión (login)
      //this.router.navigate(['/login']);
    } catch (error) {
      //TODO
    }
  }
```